# Need to restart Jenkins service programmatically on a schedule

Tags: windows, jenkins

I'd like to be able to set up a scheduled job that restarts Jenkins every night (Windows7).  Is there a way to set up a job to run that will do a safeRestart programmatically that I can put in my Windows scheduler?

Comment: It would be even more useful if we could define a job that schedules restarts during a hardcoded daily maintenance window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the safe-restart command in the [Jenkins CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI).

Comment: Can I use the API Token, or will I need to set up SSH?  I'd prefer the former.

Comment: Using SSH authentication is not working.  Getting Authentication failed. No Private key accepted.  Ugg.

Answer (score 34):

If the above CLI method did not work (in my case it failed on: hudson.security.AccessDeniedException2: anonymous is missing the Overall/Read permission)

You can create a [Groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) build step and "Execute a system Groovy script":

```
import hudson.model.*;
Hudson.instance.doSafeRestart(null);
```

or the new Jenkins instance

```
import jenkins.model.*
Jenkins.instance.doSafeRestart(null);
```

Then, you can set this job to be triggered by schedule.
For example, to restart Jenkins daily on midnight, set "Build periodically": `H 00 * * *`

Comment: IMHO this must be the answer- This is fully built into Jenkins master. Not depending on any slave or external process.

Comment: Love this solution, didn't know it was possible.

Comment: Make sure you use the build step for SYSTEM groovy script, otherwise this does not work.

Comment: See https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html doSafeRestart doSafeExit doQuietDown ...

Answer (score 5):

Posting this here for others that come here from Google. You can add a job to Jenkins to restart itself using the CLI. Add a job with a shell step to execute:

```
java -jar "$JENKINS_HOME/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar" -s "$JENKINS_URL" safe-restart
```

Answer (score 1):

For Jenkins with LDAP enabled, Direct invocation of `safe-restart` command didn't work. [This JENKINS JIRA helped](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21086?focusedCommentId=205785&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-205785)

**Login first**

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 login --username "$JCLIUSER" --password "$JCLIPASSWD"
```

**Safe Restart after that**

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 safe-restart --username "$JCLIUSER" --password "$JCLIPASSWD"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Use Jenkins Resftul API in order to restart your jenkins service, and create some crontab task that performs it on daily basis - (On Linux/Unix/Mac versions)
, The basic flags on jenkins related to restarts are:

```
--restart (force restart , terminating current session)
--safeRestart (restart after all builds and jobs are completed [Graceful restart])
```

**Example:**
The task would be:

```
curl -x POST -u <user>:<token> <jenkins-ip>/safeRestart
```

**For adding a crontab**:

```
#Go to your scripts directory
cd ~/scripts 
# edit new script file
sudo vim restart-jenkins-task.sh 
# paste the task above ^ ...
# make the script executable
chmod +x restart-jenkins-task.sh 
# add crontab task
sudo crontab -e 
# paste the following: run the new script every night at 00:00 (12 am midnight)
0 0 * * * ~/scripts/restart-jenkins-task.sh
```

**Pay Attention:**
The best practice to manage global maintenance tasks is generating some automation user that deals with the application and maintenance tasks and giving him proper permissions (*only users with administrator privilege can perform restart*).

- For Generating user access with administrator permissions (`Manage Jenkins -> Manage and Assign Roles -> Assign Roles -> create user and toggle administrator permission`),
- For generating access token for authenticating Jenkins from commandline ( `Jenkins -> Go to User -> Add new token`)